# SQL Number Serially for common row values always starting with 1 for new value

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example I have a table with values as:

```
A
A
A
C
C
D
E
E
```

And I want to result as:

```
1 A
2 A
3 A
1 C
2 C
1 D
1 E
2 E
```

Please reply with any SQL query to get above output.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: You are looking for function RANK()

Comment: what is the logic ? always 1,2,3,1,2,3 ?

Comment: You should have wrote some explanation on your input and expected result.

Comment: Tried with RANK(), but it returns unique number for unique rows.

Comment: I want Unique values with numbers starting from 1 and serially for unique values and if not unique then number as 1.

Comment: Row_number() over (partition by col order by (SELECT 1))

Comment: Here's the documentation on [Rank](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms176102.aspx).  Pay attention to the the section *A. Ranking rows within a partition*.  SO isn't a code writing service.  If you post what you've tried, we can help you with the errors/logic fails.

Comment: use `row_number() over (partition by ... order by ...)`

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
declare @t table (name nvarchar(1))

insert into @t
select 'a' union all
select 'a' union all
select 'a' union all
select 'b' union all
select 'c' union all
select 'c' union all
select 'd' 

select row_number() over(partition by name order by name) as [order], name
from @t
```